# How can I clear Zabbix errors about template prototypes?

Tags: zabbix

I updated a template and misplaced a curly bracket, so ended up with a lot of warnings about duplicate keys, carefully hidden on the 'Discovery rules' page.

Now I've fixed the template and uploaded it again, the red [i] is still there and still has the old errors in it.

How can I clear those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will be automatically cleared the next time the LLD rule is processed for that host. As discovery rules often are scheduled to run once per hour, it could take a bit more than an hour for it to clear.

Since Zabbix 4.0, one can also [force immediate check](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/introduction/whatsnew400#retrieve_metrics_immediately) of passive type LLD rules.

Comment: Thanks for this. A shame there's no 'run now' button! And that the errors are so carefully hidden!

Comment: Actually, passive-type LLD rules can be forced to be checked since Zabbix 4.0 - included that detail in the answer.